# How to count unique counts of each string from the pandas list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks as in the below format (2 columns of pandas data frame). Column name has the ID and the column menu has the string inside the list.

```
name | menu

A    | [cheese, cake, sausage]
B    | [chicken, cake, water]
C    | [chicken, sausage, water]
D    | [water, cheese, sausage]
...
...
```

The result I want to see from here through code is the name of the menu and its frequency by order as below.

```
sausage 3
water 3 
cheese 2
cake 2
chicken 2
...
...
```

How do I extract strings inside from the list from a pandas column and then count its number?

Comment: you can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the `menu` column and [count the values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column `menu` contains lists, you can run (as suggested in the comments):

```
df.explode('menu')['menu'].value_counts()
```

Or to wrap it in a new df:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.explode('menu')['menu'].value_counts()).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'word', 'menu': 'count'}, inplace=False)
```

result:

|  | word | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | water | 3 |
| 1 | sausage | 3 |
| 2 | cake | 2 |
| 3 | chicken | 2 |
| 4 | cheese | 2 |